# Calculate function on a column of nested tibbles?

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I have a dataframe with a column of tibbles.
Here is a portion of my data:

```
date        time        uuid                data
2018-06-23  18:25:24    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>    
2018-06-23  18:25:38    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>    
2018-06-23  18:26:01    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>    
2018-06-23  18:26:23    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>    
2018-06-23  18:26:37    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>    
2018-06-23  18:27:00    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>    
2018-06-23  18:27:22    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>    
2018-06-23  18:27:39    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>    
2018-06-23  18:28:06    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>    
2018-06-23  18:28:30    0b27ea5fad61c99d    <tibble>
```

And this is my function:

```
jaccard <- function(vector1, vector2) {

  return(length(intersect(vector1, vector2)) / 
        length(union(vector1, vector2)))

}
```

My data column consists of tibbles with one column of characters:

```
contacts
5646
65748
115
498456
35135
```

My goal is to calculate jaccard between each 2 consecutive tibbles in the data column.

I have tried:

`df %>% mutate(j = jaccard(data, lag(data, 1)))` but it doesn't seem to work for some reason.

I know I am close, please advise.

Comment: the solution is ok but the numbers are wrong. I need to access to each data row with [[]] and take the contacts column. @mkr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `jaccard` function is not written to handle vector arguments. As you know that functions used as part of `mutate` receive a vector of data (vector of `10 tibbles` in case of OP's example). Now, since `jaccard` function is not written to handle arguments of vector(vector of tibbles) the result will not meet expectation.

The easiest fix can be to vectorise `jaccard` function so that it can  handle vector arguments. Once can use `Vectorize` to convert the function as:

```
# Function 
jaccard <- function(vector1, vector2) {
  return(length(intersect(vector1, vector2)) / 
           length(union(vector1, vector2)))
}
# Vectorised version of jaccard function
jaccardV <- Vectorize(jaccard)


library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(j = jaccardV(data, lag(data, 1)))

#          date     time             uuid                            data         j
# 1  2018-06-23 18:25:24 0b27ea5fad61c99d 5646, 65748, 115, 498456, 35135 0.0000000
# 2  2018-06-23 18:25:38 0b27ea5fad61c99d                     5646, 65748 0.4000000
# 3  2018-06-23 18:26:01 0b27ea5fad61c99d                5646, 65748, 115 0.6666667
# 4  2018-06-23 18:26:23 0b27ea5fad61c99d                            5646 0.3333333
# 5  2018-06-23 18:26:37 0b27ea5fad61c99d                     5646, 65748 0.5000000
# 6  2018-06-23 18:27:00 0b27ea5fad61c99d 5646, 65748, 115, 498456, 35135 0.4000000
# 7  2018-06-23 18:27:22 0b27ea5fad61c99d                     5646, 65748 0.4000000
# 8  2018-06-23 18:27:39 0b27ea5fad61c99d                5646, 65748, 115 0.6666667
# 9  2018-06-23 18:28:06 0b27ea5fad61c99d                            5646 0.3333333
# 10 2018-06-23 18:28:30 0b27ea5fad61c99d                     5646, 65748 0.5000000
```

**Data:**

```
df <- read.table(text="
date        time        uuid                
2018-06-23  18:25:24    0b27ea5fad61c99d    
2018-06-23  18:25:38    0b27ea5fad61c99d    
2018-06-23  18:26:01    0b27ea5fad61c99d    
2018-06-23  18:26:23    0b27ea5fad61c99d    
2018-06-23  18:26:37    0b27ea5fad61c99d    
2018-06-23  18:27:00    0b27ea5fad61c99d    
2018-06-23  18:27:22    0b27ea5fad61c99d    
2018-06-23  18:27:39    0b27ea5fad61c99d    
2018-06-23  18:28:06    0b27ea5fad61c99d    
2018-06-23  18:28:30    0b27ea5fad61c99d",
header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

t1 <- tibble(contacts = c(5646,65748,115,498456,35135))
t2 <- tibble(contacts = c(5646,65748))
t3 <- tibble(contacts = c(5646,65748,115))
t4 <- tibble(contacts = c(5646))
t5 <- tibble(contacts = c(5646,65748))


df$data <- c(t1,t2,t3,t4,t5)

df
#          date     time             uuid                            data
# 1  2018-06-23 18:25:24 0b27ea5fad61c99d 5646, 65748, 115, 498456, 35135
# 2  2018-06-23 18:25:38 0b27ea5fad61c99d                     5646, 65748
# 3  2018-06-23 18:26:01 0b27ea5fad61c99d                5646, 65748, 115
# 4  2018-06-23 18:26:23 0b27ea5fad61c99d                            5646
# 5  2018-06-23 18:26:37 0b27ea5fad61c99d                     5646, 65748
# 6  2018-06-23 18:27:00 0b27ea5fad61c99d 5646, 65748, 115, 498456, 35135
# 7  2018-06-23 18:27:22 0b27ea5fad61c99d                     5646, 65748
# 8  2018-06-23 18:27:39 0b27ea5fad61c99d                5646, 65748, 115
# 9  2018-06-23 18:28:06 0b27ea5fad61c99d                            5646
# 10 2018-06-23 18:28:30 0b27ea5fad61c99d                     5646, 65748
```

Comment: Still doesn't meet the expectation...
I get 0 and 1, while jaccard of each 2 tibbles isn't 0 or 1...

Comment: the solution is ok but the numbers are wrong. I need to access to each data row with [[]] and take the contacts column. @mkr

Comment: @steves You can do that. I think it would be better if you can share output of `dput(head(df))`. I can verify the output as well. One more point. You have used `length` in jaccard function  but you should use `nrow` as your arguments are data.frame or tibble  Please try with `nrow` once.

Comment: It doesn't work with `nrow` tried. For contacts you see a head of an example tibble, you can take a similar one and try with 2 rows.
For me it doesn't do what I need.
The only way it works is if I run a for loop with `jaccard(df$data[[1]]$contacts, df$data[[2]]$contacts))`

Comment: Thanks @mkr, I need your help, please advise. Meanwhile I am playing around to see how to solve this.

Comment: @steves I have modified my answer to include sample data. I think it works correctly for sample data used by me. Have look and let me know if you feel otherwise.

Comment: Still doens't work like your solution the only thing that is different is that your t1 - t5 are tibbles and you actually see them. In my case I have them as tibbles: <tibble>.
Still wrong @mkr